# The condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used. What changes to make?

Tags: r

When i run the below function, i get the output for just one value.
with a message,
"the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

What changes do i need to make to get all values?

```
ownsquare <- function(n)
{
  for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 506, by = 0.001))
  {
    r <- i * i
    if (r <= n) x=i
  }
 x 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean you get an error for just one value?? I tried ownsquare(5) and the result seems fine...

Comment: n is a vector? then you are comparing i to whole of n

Comment: also , that x will not be defined at all for cases your condition is not met.

Comment: Also, `sqrt` should be about a million times faster.

Comment: @User2321im trying to use this function for 510 values at a time. it displays the 1st value fine. but the remaining 509 values are not displayed.

Comment: @R.S. i know i could use sqrt but im trying an own function here

Comment: How do you "use this function for 510 values at a time" ?

Comment: When you give a vector as the argument to `if` only the first element is tested. You probably need to be using `ifelse` or maybe `which`, rather than a `for` loop. The other option might be to convert the ownsquare so it is capable of handling a multi-element vector. See `?Vectorize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way to vectorize this function is to use `ifelse` instead of `if`:

```
ownsquare2 <- function(n)
{
    for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 506, by = 0.001))
    {
        r <- i * i
        x <- ifelse(r <= n, i, x)
    }
    x 
}
ownsquare2(1:10)
## [1] 1.000 1.414 1.732 2.000 2.236 2.449 2.645 2.828 3.000 3.162
```

Here, `x` is treated as a vector in the function, and the substitution used in the `if` expression is vectorized with `ifelse`.

The translation from `if` to `ifelse` is fairly straightforward, but becomes unreadable (IMO) for chained if-else code.

Comment: It possible to implement the `break` in this code, but it is not as easy as with 42-'s code which vectorizes with a loop in R code (`Vectorize`).  This, while this code is actually vectorized at the C level, as it is, it is still much slower than the `Vectorize` solution with `break`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create a function that can do the same operation on multiple values, returning a vector of equal length as its argument. In R parlance that behavior of a function is known as "vectorization". And there is a wrapper function around the `mapply` function that is named `Vectorize`. This illustrates its use with your function which does work correctly on a single element:

```
 Vownsquare <- Vectorize(ownsquare)
 Vownsquare( 1:10 )
 #-------
 [1] 1.000 1.414 1.732 2.000 2.236 2.449 2.645 2.828 3.000 3.162
```

It's really slow, but this is the result of an inefficient implementation. Might improve your efficiency by learning to use `break`. This avoids the unnecessary iteration after the condition r>n  is reached.

```
 ownsquare <- function(n)
 {
   for (i in seq(from = 1, to = 506, by = 0.001))
   {
     r <- i * i
     if (r > n) { x=i; break() }
   }
  x 
 }
 Vownsquare <- Vectorize(ownsquare)
 Vownsquare( 1:10 )
[1] 1.001 1.415 1.733 2.001 2.237 2.450 2.646 2.829 3.001 3.163
```

Notice this comparison of Lundberg's implementation that computes the full 506,000 length vector for each argument:

```
 system.time(ownsquare2(1:10))   # makes full vectors
   user  system elapsed 
  7.311   0.069   7.292 

 system.time(ownsquare(1:10))    # uses break
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.000   0.008 

 system.time(Vownsquareoriginal( 1:10 ))  # full vectors with if()
   user  system elapsed 
  3.746   0.040   3.729
```

Comment: Thanks.  That answers my question, which overwhelms the computation, the `Vectorize` or the full comparison with `ifelse`.  The answer is clear.

Comment: `Ifelse` creates 2 vectors of full length in order to make the comparison. I think that is why the `for-if()` strategy is twice as fast.